# How to speed up panning and zooming using smoothZoom jquery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, smooth-scrolling, panning

Hello I am currently using the smoothZoom plugin in a project (http://codecanyon.net/item/smooth-zoom-pan-jquery-image-viewer/511142).
I have to load in an image of roughly 2500 * 2500 pixels (the client is insistant on this size not being changed otherwise I would just resize the image).

Does anybody know any ways to make the panning and zooming smoother?

At the moment the operation of the smoothZoom is very sluggish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, what causes the operation of the smoothZoom to be sluggish is the client's hardware & browser. Not the plugin itself. 2500x2500 is a very large image, and the rendering of any animation can cause heavy usage of CPU.

Comment: So other than resizing the image is there anything I can do to improve performance? I wondered if there is anything like a malloc command from c++.

Comment: I don't think there's much you can do on this. Though, dropping the jpeg's quality without resizing it might help.

Comment: OK brilliant thanks for your help. I thoguht there was little I could do but its worth asking incase someone knows better.